# Slashes added to JSON

Tags: php, json

In live server unwanted slashes appending to encoding JSON, wherever single quote present.

Actually i'm trying to do rename Number as Nu'mber, just adding a single in between.

> PHP Version 5.3.21

`Result:  {"values":"Nu\\'mber","lastvalue":"Number"}`

i.e. `' replaced with \\'`

whereas in my local-server, its working perfectly

> PHP Version 5.3.13

```
Result: {"values":"Nu'mber","lastvalue":"Number"}
```

Also, i used stripslashes(), but no use of it. in some cases, i have to reuse the result JSON if i do that, more slashes appended .is this PHP version problem?

Comment: Where does that JSON come from? At what point do you get the slashes? Is this a value submitted *to* PHP? Is this a value generated *by* PHP?

Comment: I'm getting the result like this .{"values":"Nu\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'mber","lastvalue":"Nu\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'mber"}.here im fetching the "values" and showing it to user. so in that case instead of displaying `Nu'mber` its displayed as `Nu\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'mber`

Comment: **Clarify "getting the result", please!** Where does what come from?

Comment: are you retrieving the json string from a database?

Comment: Thanks Guys. magic_quotes_gpc = Off solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). You can turn them off in php.ini or in the code.

From te manual, in php.ini:

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Or in your php code:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that my localserver has magicquotesgpc "off" and live server has on